# How to pass Range to VBA Basic Function for NPV formula

Tags: excel, vba, vba6

I am trying to simplify the NPV function for PV0. The existing formula discounts the first number in the array, so to find the true NPV, you have to do "=NPV(rate, B2:B6) + A1" if:

[[image: Excel Cells1]

Here is my code:

```
Function True_NPV(rate, PV0, CF_Series As Range)
True_NPV = NPV(rate, CF_Series) + PV0

End Function
```

When I do "=True_NPV(10%, B1, B2:B6)", I get this error message:
"Compile Error:
Type Mismatch: Array or user-defined type expected"

I'd appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to complete this, I couldn't find anything similar and struggled with the docs. I have just started learning VBA Basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`WorksheetFunction.Npv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.npv).

```
True_NPV = WorksheetFunction.Npv(rate, CF_Series) + PV0
```

[image]

The [`NPV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/npv-function) function (from `VBA.Financial`) expects an array of `Double` as its second parameter, hence your error.